# #pragma directive suppresses the warnings in the page it is specified or for the entire application?

Tags: c#, warnings, suppress-warnings

I have one question:

when I use warning directive #pragma in one of the class file where I get the warning as "#pragma warning disable " then these specified warnings will be suppressed for entire application or only for that page?

Comment: Tip, you have asked 15 questions of which 11 are answered of which 1 is marked as answered. It might be an idea to accept some. If you don't you get a note next to your name with your acceptance percentage. You can then get that note removed by marking answeres as accepted, or you can already start ahead and mark some as answered.

Comment: Also, marking an answer as accepted you get +2 rep.

Comment: Thanks @SynerCoder for letting me know this...I was unaware of that..

Comment: K T - you are still unaware of it? Why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the suppression is active until the end of file or until you restore the warnings.

The right paragraph in the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) is 9.5.8 that does not mention this fact.
It can be inferred from section 9.5.1 where the specification talks about: conditional compilation symbols.

See the following post for an exhaustive explanation:

[C#: Is pragma warning restore needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556771/c-is-pragma-warning-restore-needed)

Answer (score 1):

The pre-processor directives are applied only to the compilation unit where they are defined, in that case it is the class file where you used them

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `#pragma warning disable` it is enabled until the end of the file.'

I quote from the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (9.5.1):

> The symbol remains defined until a #undef directive for that same
>   symbol is processed, or until the end of the source file is reached.